# What does this code do in magento? $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');

Tags: magento-1.9, php, model, class, methods

This is my model Class

```
<?php

class Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');
}
}
?>
```

My question is What does this code do in magento?

**$this->_init('weblog/blogpost');**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It initiates the resource model this model uses to commit data to the database.

So in this case that would be the file `app/code/[local|community]/Magentotutorials/Weblog/Model/Resource/Blogpost.php`

[EDIT] to answer @easymoden00b question, the `_init` method can be found in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` which directly calls `_setResourceModel` in the same class

```
/**
 * Set resource names
 *
 * If collection name is ommited, resource name will be used with _collection appended
 *
 * @param string $resourceName
 * @param string|null $resourceCollectionName
 */
protected function _setResourceModel($resourceName, $resourceCollectionName=null)
{
    $this->_resourceName = $resourceName;
    if (is_null($resourceCollectionName)) {
        $resourceCollectionName = $resourceName.'_collection';
    }
    $this->_resourceCollectionName = $resourceCollectionName;
}
```

This stores the Resource item and collection class names for further use when retrieving and writting to and from the database

Comment: related:  what does the _init() function do?

Comment: @easymoden00b made an edit :)